# VIew is not accessing the Model values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a view,model and controller in my application. What I need is to pass the textbox value to a view and display on the result page.

```
Index.cshtml


  @model MvcApplication5.Models.Employee
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
     }
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    <div>
    <h1>Employee </h1>

    </div>
     @using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayForm", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post))
      {  
        @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.username)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company)
        <button type="submit" id="ajax_method">submit </button>

      }
```

> Controller

```
    public ActionResult DisplayForm(Employee model)
      {
         var employeeName = model.username;
         var company = model.Company;
         return View("Validateresult");
      }
```

> ```
>    Model
> ```

```
        public class Employee
        {          
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string Company { get; set; }

        }
```

> and validateresult.cshtml

```
    @model MvcApplication5.Models.Employee     
    <h2>Validateresult</h2>
    <div>    
        <div>username:
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.username)


        </div>
    </div>
```

It seems a silly issue but im unable to find the reason why it's not displaying the username that i enter in to the textbox. The value is accessible in the controller but not in the view.

Comment: `return View("Validateresult");` to  `return View("Validateresult",model);`

Answer (score 3):

You're not passing the model to the view.
In controller, change  `return View("Validateresult");` to `return View("Validateresult", model);`